# Lightning Component - User lookup in list

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have 3 things that I am trying to accomplish that I can't figure out how, I have based the list off the trailhead unit too.

- Displaying full name of case owner using Owner.Username (just displays blank, is there a way to get this to work?)
- Lookup of the owner to redirect to the user page (currently redirects to the case, not sure how to handle with two indexes in the one iteration)
- display chatter photo of the case owner (not sure how to do this and couldn't find much info on this either)

Component:

```
     <aura:component controller="Case_List_DPI_Controller" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
      <aura:attribute name="cases" type="List" />
      <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
      <!--
        Use a data table from the Lightning Design System:
        https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/
      -->
      <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--striped slds-table--cell-buffer slds-table--fixed-layout">
        <thead>
          <tr class="slds-text-heading--label">
            <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Case Life (Business Days)">Case Life (Business Days)</div></th>
            <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Subject">Subject</div></th>
            <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Owner">Owner</div></th>
            <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Type">Type</div></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <!-- Use the Apex model and controller to fetch server side data -->
          <aura:iteration items="{!v.cases}" var="case" indexVar="index">
            <tr>
              <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!case.Case_Life_Days_Business_Days__c}">{!case.Case_Life_Days_Business_Days__c}</div></td>
              <td><a onclick="{!c.navigateToRecord}" style="width:100%;" data-index="{!index}">{!case.Subject}</a></td>
              <td><a onclick="{!c.navigateToUser}" style="width:100%;" data-index="{!index}">{!case.Owner.Username}</a></td>
              <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!case.RecordType.Name}">{!case.RecordType.Name}</div></td>
              <td>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
    ({
  doInit: function(component, event, helper) {      
    // Fetch the account list from the Apex controller   
    helper.getCaseList(component);
  },
  deleteAccount: function(component, event, helper) {
    // Prevent the form from getting submitted
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the value from the field that's in the form
    var caseSubject = event.target.getElementsByClassName('case-subject')[0].value;
    confirm('Delete the ' + caseSubject + ' account? (don’t worry, this won’t actually work!)');
  },
  navigateToRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
        var idx = event.target.getAttribute('data-index');
        var cases = component.get("v.cases")[idx];
        var navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject"); 
        if(navEvent){
            navEvent.setParams({
                  recordId: cases.Id,
                  slideDevName: "detail"
            });
            navEvent.fire(); 
        }
        else{
            window.location.href = '/one/one.app#/sObject/'+cases.Id+'/view'
        }
    },
    navigateToUser : function(component, event, helper) {
        var idx = event.target.getAttribute('data-index');
        var cases = component.get("v.cases")[idx];
        var navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject"); 
        if(navEvent){
            navEvent.setParams({
                  recordId: cases.OwnerId,
                  slideDevName: "detail"
            });
            navEvent.fire(); 
        }
        else{
            window.location.href = '/one/one.app#/sObject/'+cases.OwnerId+'/view'
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: The user redirect is actually working now, might not have saved or refreshed the page properly

Comment: sorry figured out the name issue to I should of just been using 'Name' not 'USername'

Comment: ok so I figured out I can display a users photo using smallPhotoURL and applying the same css salesforce uses (just inspect element in standard lightning record layout) however this does not work on standard owner fields in salesforce as you can only pull basic standard fields and not the full range of standard fields as well as any custom fields.  have found a few other threads in similar issue but not sure how to apply it to a lightning apex controller